# Chrome extension install force list not working?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I tried to configure  force-installed extension as mentioned at chrome  [documentation](http://dev.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#ExtensionInstallForcelist).
I created registry key like this

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Google\Chrome\ExtensionInstallForcelist]
"1"="gbchcmhmhahfdphkhkmpfmihenigjmpp;https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx"
```

but extension not installed. 
Also I tried update url like this `https://clients2.google.com/` .
And in [chrome://policy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTOwV.png)  I didn't find policy for this extension.

Comment: Did you check the value was added in `regedit`?

Comment: Yes. Value was added

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your machine is in Active Directory Domain in order to force install extension. Try reloading policy. Policy value should not be empty [image: chrome://policy]